# On vscode debugger restart, postDebugTask is run but not preLaunchTask

Tags: docker, gdb, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I'm running unit tests using googletests on embedded C software and I'm using a docker container to be able to run them easily on any platform. Now I would like to debug these unit tests from vscode connecting to my docker container and running gdb in it.

I managed to configure launch.json and tasks.json to start and run the debug session.

launch.json :

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "tests debug",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "/project/build/tests/bin/tests",
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "/project",
      "environment": [],
      "sourceFileMap": {
        "/usr/include/": "/usr/src/"
      },
      "preLaunchTask": "start debugger",
      "postDebugTask": "stop debugger",
      "pipeTransport": {
        "debuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
        "pipeProgram": "docker",
        "pipeArgs": ["exec", "-i", "debug", "sh", "-c"],
        "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
      },
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "start debugger",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "docker run --privileged -v /path/to/my/project:/project --name debug -it --rm gtest-cmock",
      "isBackground": true,
      "problemMatcher": {
        "pattern": [
          {
            "regexp": ".",
            "file": 1,
            "location": 2,
            "message": 3
          }
        ],
        "background": {
          "activeOnStart": true,
          "beginsPattern": ".",
          "endsPattern": "."
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "stop debugger",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "docker stop -t 0 debug",
    }
  ]
}
```

When I hit the debugger restart button, stop debugger task is run and the docker container stops but start debugger is not run. The debug session hangs and I have to close vscode do be able to run another debug session.
I'm looking for a way to either run both tasks on debugger restart, or to run none (if I start my docker from another terminal and deactivate both tasks, restart works with no problem).